# How can I convert many statement mysql dinamis to laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Mysql query like this :

```sql
SET @sql_dinamis = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'SUM( IF(id_barang=', id_barang, ',jml_bk,0) ) AS br',
            id_barang
        )
    )
    FROM barang_keluar
);

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT month(tgl_keluar) as m, ',@sql_dinamis,'
    FROM barang_keluar
    WHERE month(tgl_keluar) and year(tgl_keluar)=2019
    GROUP BY month(tgl_keluar)'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I want to convert it to Laravel Eloquent, but I'm confused. Because there exist many statement. There exist `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, `SET`, `DEALLOCATE` etc. You can see query above.

How can I convert it to Laravel Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually prepare statements (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, `DEALLOCATE`) in Laravel since the Query Builder calls `PDO::prepare`, `PDO::bindValue` and `PDO::execute` behind the scenes.

You will be responsable for escaping/sanitizing the input however.

You can achieve this query by using a few raw methods with the query builder.

After some experimentation, I found out the real sql query created by your code is something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    month(tgl_keluar) as m,
    SUM(IF(id_barang=1,jml_bk,0)) AS br42,
    SUM(IF(id_barang=2,jml_bk,0)) AS br48,
    SUM(IF(id_barang=3,jml_bk,0)) AS br13,
    SUM(IF(id_barang=4,jml_bk,0)) AS br14,
    .
    .
    .
    SUM(IF(id_barang=n-1,jml_bk,0)) AS brn-1
    SUM(IF(id_barang=n,jml_bk,0)) AS brn
FROM barang_keluar
WHERE month(tgl_keluar) AND year(tgl_keluar)=2019
GROUP BY month(tgl_keluar)
```

To translate this into the query builder, we'll need 2 queries:

```php
/**
 * Equivalent to
 * 
 * SELECT
 *     id_barang 
 * FROM barang_keluar;
 */
$ids_barang = DB::table('barang_keluar')
              ->select('id_barang')
              ->get();
```

```php
/**
 * Equivalent to
 *
 * SELECT
 *     month(tgl_keluar) as m,
 * FROM barang_keluar
 * WHERE month(tgl_keluar) AND year(tgl_keluar)=2019
 * GROUP BY `m`;
 */

// Pass year as a variable if you want. You can also hardcode it
$year = 2019;
$query = DB::table('barang_keluar')
         ->selectRaw('month(tgl_keluar) as m')
         ->whereRaw('month(tgl_keluar) and year(tgl_keluar)=?', [$year])
         ->groupBy('m');
```

Since we didn't call `->get()`, we can still add to the query.

```php
// Now, we add all the `SUM()` statements.
foreach ($ids_barang as $row) {
    $query->selectRaw("sum(if(eme_id=?,eme_empresa_id,0)) as br{$row->id_barang}", [$row->id_barang]);
}
// And finally, get the query results
$results = $query->get();
```

You can verify this produces the query by dumping `$query->>toSql()`.

Comment: I have tried the above and the results are like the picture I sent above
   
this is what I'm trying :

  
{ $brgs = BarangKeluar::selectRaw("month(tgl_keluar) as m")
                        ->selectRaw("group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(id_barang = ',id_barang,', jml_bk, 0)) as br', id_barang))")
                        ->whereRaw("month(tgl_keluar) and year(tgl_keluar)")
                        ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(tgl_keluar)"))->get()->toArray();

}

Comment: thank you sir, very good explanation and already approaching the results I mean. I tried it and the results: enter image description here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0r4M.png
But jml_bk (quantity) doesn't seem to work and doesn't get a pack value.

Comment: In order to get results like this:

array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
        "m" => 1
        "br2" => 100
    "br3" => 200  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
        "m" => 7
        "br1" => 100
    "br2" => 200"
  ]
]

Comment: m = is as a month, br (id_product) from as br1, br2 etc and br (id_product) = 100 (quantity of sum and group by month)

please explain again sir, thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure this SQL query worked before? I'm trying to run it but it produces similar results to your image.

Comment: You could edit your question and post the `barang_keluar` table structure. That way it might be easier to find a working query.

Comment: I tried in SQL using the query above to get the results page. but from putting it into laravel in order to get the results, what can it be, sir?

Comment: this is an example of my table structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvWVQ.png

thanks sir

Comment: thank you sir, after I edited it a few, and the results were good and as expected. Thank you, sir

Comment: in the query section I edited :

$query->selectRaw("sum(if(id_barang={$row->id_barang},jml_bk,0)) as br{$row->id_barang}", [$row->id_barang], "group by id_barang");

Comment: I want to ask again, how can I get the results ['br1', 'br2', 'br3'] from your query above sir?
because I input the data on morris chart. example ykeys: ['a', 'b'],

Comment: i made like this $dbr[] = "br{$bbr}"; but result error 'Array to string conversion'

Comment: In `"br{$bbr}"`, `$bbr` must be a string.